# Count the number of occurrences of each item in an array and regex

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the result of the below array though no idea what am I missing here,

```js
[
    {
        "Id": "10",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "11",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "12",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "13",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "14",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T17:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P3",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T17:36:48Z"
    }
]
```

And I am trying to obtain below output

```js
[
    {
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook",
        "TechnicalBook_Count": "2"
    },
    {
        "FileName": "SocialBook",
        "SocialBook_Count": "3"
    }
]
```

Below code, I tried though not getting the proper output, any alternate suggestions here? Because 'FileName' will change every time, new DateTime will append in FileName.

```js
var occurrences = { };
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   occurrences[arr[i]] = (occurrences[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
```

Comment: `arr[i]` is an object. `occurences[arr[i]]` will therefor be `occurences["[object Object]"]` for every entry in `arr`

Comment: A first step would be to extract the first part of `arr[i].FileName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var data =
[
    {
        "Id": "10",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "11",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "12",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "13",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "14",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T17:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P3",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T17:36:48Z"
    }
]

var prefixesAll = data.map(a => a.FileName.split('_')[0]);

var prefixesUnique = [...new Set(prefixesAll)];

var prefixCounts = prefixesUnique.map(a => ({
  "FileName": a,
  "Count": data.filter(b => b.FileName.startsWith(a)).length
}));

console.log(prefixesAll);
console.log(prefixesUnique);
console.log(prefixCounts);
```

In an array of objects you should always aim for each object to have the same keys, so I've done that here.

That code will output all of the prefixes, then a unique list of the prefixes, then the count of each prefix:

```
[
  "TechnicalBook",
  "SocialBook",
  "TechnicalBook",
  "SocialBook",
  "SocialBook"
]

[
  "TechnicalBook",
  "SocialBook"
]

[
  {
    "FileName": "TechnicalBook",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "FileName": "SocialBook",
    "Count": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Robson, let me try this. It looks very simple to compare to what I was trying.

Comment: The three separate steps can all be done with one single `.reduce()` call

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is not so much counting occurrences but transforming data from one format into another.  However, you only need to take a couple of steps to convert your data into another format.  See comments below...

```
// your data
var dataArr = [
    {
        "Id": "10",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "11",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T12:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P1",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "12",
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "ABC P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T12:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "13",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T15:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P2",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T15:36:48Z"
    },
    {
        "Id": "14",
        "FileName": "SocialBook_2021-08-26T17:36:48Z",
        "Book": "XYZ P3",
        "Location": "USA",
        "LastModified": "2021-08-26T17:36:48Z"
    }
];

// create storage object
var fileObject = {};

// loop through data
dataArr.forEach(d => {
    // get the fileName (remove date)
    let fileName = d.FileName.split("_")[0];

    // check if fileObject has a fileName property
    // if not add it and set it to 0
    fileObject[fileName] = fileObject[fileName] || 0,

    // then/else increment the count
    fileObject[fileName] += 1
}),
```

This will give you:

```
console.log("fileObject:", fileObject)

//=> fileObject: { TechnicalBook: 2, SocialBook: 3 }
```

Now that you've done the counting then it's simply a matter of reformatting:

```
// create output array
var bookArr = [];

// loop through fileObject
Object.keys(fileObject).forEach(key => {
    // create a temporary object
    let obj = {
        FileName: key
    };

    // add the count to obj
    obj[`${key}_Count`] = fileObject[key],
    
    // add obj to the array
    bookArr.push(obj)
})
```

This will give you:

```
console.log("bookArr:", bookArr)

/*=> bookArr: [ { FileName: 'TechnicalBook', TechnicalBook_Count: 2 },
{ FileName: 'SocialBook', SocialBook_Count: 3 } ]
*/
```

And as you seem to want the output in JSON format then:

```
var bookJSON = JSON.stringify(bookArr, null, 4);

console.log(bookJSON)

/*
[
    {
        "FileName": "TechnicalBook",
        "TechnicalBook_Count": 2
    },
    {
        "FileName": "SocialBook",
        "SocialBook_Count": 3
    }
]
*/
```

Hoped that helped. :)